# Who was shown on the TV towards the end of the movie?

Tags: good-night-and-good-luck

Near the end of [*Good Night, and Good Luck.*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0433383/), when *Ed* and *Fred* are leaving *William Paley*'s office after he cut down their show, they walk past a TV screen (on which the camera focusses before cutting to the frame story of *Ed Murrow*'s speech) showing a speech of someone in a smoking talking about the habeas corpus principle and its implications (obviously in relation to the *McCarthy* case).

I wonder **who was speaking in this apparently historical footage.** I'm asking because I thought that might even have been footage of the real *Edward R. Murrow*, which would have been quite an anachronistic reference. But given the lack of acquaintance with the historical background of the story and the real persons involved I wasn't sure about this nor able to verify this guess that easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a clip of [President Dwight David Eisenhower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwight_D._Eisenhower) from a speech he made after receiving the America's Democratic Legacy Award at a [B'nai B'rith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%27nai_B%27rith) Dinner in honour of the 40th Anniversary of the [Anti-Defamation League](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Defamation_League) on November 23rd 1953 at 19:54 EST (according to the [Eisenhower archives](http://www.eisenhower.archives.gov/education/bsa/citizenship_merit_badge/speeches/bnai_brith_dinner.pdf) which is a US Government source).

The only video I can find of this is very low quality as it has been recorded with a camera from a screen, but you can tell it's original as it's much longer:

And a screenshot from the film to compare:

[image: Image of Eisenhower in Good Night, And Good Luck]